# AJAX callback effects with jQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax, effect

I stumbled upon a problem. I'm using a simple AJAX script written in jQuery, I want to make the AJAX callback to change html with easeInOut effect for example, but I don't know how to do it, because now, when the response comes, div's content changes with some kind of blinking effect, that is very ugly, I assume that is the default "effect".

The script: (I tried to add `.fadeOut('slow')` to the `html()` method, but nothing changed)

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "institutions-filter.action",
    data: data,
    cache: false,
    success: function(result){
        $("#display-block").html(result);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hide it before changing the html, then show it:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "institutions-filter.action",
    data: data,
    cache: false,
    success: function(result)
    {
        var $el = $("#display-block");

        $el.fadeOut(400, function()
        {
            $el.html(result).fadeIn(400);
        });
    }
});
```

Change `400` to whatever duration you want...

Comment: Amazing, the "Thank you" is not enough to thank you. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "institutions-filter.action",
                data: data,
                cache: false,
                success: function(result){
                 $("#display-block").html(result).fadeTo("slow", 1);
                }
            });
```

Comment: Thanks, but still, fadeTo is my favourite effect like 'easyInOut' and I use it on all my projects :]

Answer (score 0):

You have to

```
$("#display-block").hide().html(result).fadeIn('slow');
```

Or

```
$("#display-block").fadeOut('slow').html(result).fadeIn('slow');
```

Comment: I already used a Joseph Silber solution, but I'l vot up for you :) Thanks.

Comment: you need to use the callbacks for effects to chain them together correctly.